# Javascript or jQuery Plugin or trick to slide tab head

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, slide

I have this tab : 
[image]

Is there any JS or jquery plugin or maybe just a trick to do action when the user click the arrow button on the right, the head (not the content) of the tab slide to the left, so hidden tab can be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin, but I'm not here to find one for you.
Instead I'll show you how it can be done in a couple of jQuery lines.

You need to set an overflowed `UL` element and animate it's `scrollLeft` position.
One way to track if the element is scrolled to the maximum - before resetting the position to 0 is to calculate (pseudo:)

```
ULScrollWidth - ULcurrentScrollleftPos === ULwidth ?
```

Here you go:

```js
var $navUl = $('nav ul');
$navUl[0].scrollLeft = 0;

$('nav > span').click(function(){
  var x = $navUl[0].scrollWidth - $navUl[0].scrollLeft <= $navUl.innerWidth() ? 0 : "+=100";
  $navUl.animate({scrollLeft : x});
});
```

```css
nav{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:450px;
}
nav > span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:#ddf;
  height:100%;
  line-height:80px;
  width:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
#navi{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:400px;
  padding:0;
  background:#eee;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#navi li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:30px;
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="navi">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Work</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Behance</li>
    <li>Dribbble</li>
    <li>Linked</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <span>&raquo;</span>
</nav>
```